# Why is the text inside the button not targeted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Im just curious why the linethrough worked on everything even the textbox placeholders but not with the text inside all the buttons, with css or not.
``

```
function strike(){
  document.getElementById("root").style.textDecoration= "line-through";
  }
  function unstrike(){
    document.getElementById("root").style.textDecoration= null;
    }
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      
      <Form state={userIsRegistered} />
      <button onClick={strike}>strike</button>
      <button onClick={unstrike}>unstrike</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

``

Even if i targeted the root. What should I do to include it when i click on the strike button?

Comment: Buttons have default text-decoration set

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("root") //-> it get the root element of React
```

So if you set the **style.textDecoration** for this element, every things inside it changed. But the button with out a **HTML Formatting Elements** will not inherit this style.

```js
function App() {
  const strike = () => {
    document.getElementById("root").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  };
  const unstrike = () => {
    document.getElementById("root").style.textDecoration = null;
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Form state={userIsRegistered} />
      <button onClick={strike}>
        <p>strike</p>
      </button>
      <button onClick={unstrike}>
        <p>unstrike</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi! may i ask what you mean by "without a HTML Formatting Elements"? and is there a way to select everything wherein the button text will also be  included?

Comment: Oh my bad, HTML Formatting Elements is HTML contains several elements for defining text with a special meaning.
see more: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

In your case, you can use the interface Node.childNodes to get a list of child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The text inside of a button does not inherit its outer elements properties. This applies to font also.

Line through is a "unusual" property, so even if you check developer options (inspect element) the user agent stylesheet does not have a `line-through` property, but still the text appears without line through, the reason is: there is highest specification coming from browser UA that buttons will have **only** those properties, which are defined in the default user agent stylesheet.

So, you need to set `text decoration` property to line through for button, separately

Comment: It's a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Amirhossein it's an answer. But it's not true. Buttons do inherit properties. They just have a default style which has higher specificity than inheritance

Comment: @Konrad try `<b>this<button>hi</button></b>`

Comment: @Ravi go into computed in the dev tools and find `font-weight`. You will see that it's there, buttons just have some default styles